# Partially mocking an ASP.Net MVC action method in Rhino Mock?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, mocking, rhino-mocks

I'm new to Rhino, and wondered how to mock a local variable/object inside a method of a class I'd also be mocking.  In this case I'd be doing it with an ASP.Net MVC controller & action method.

Here's what the controller looks like, simplified:

```
public class HomeController : Controller  {

   public myObjectType myMockedObject; //I want to mock this
   public myNonMockedObject;           //don't want to mock this
   public ViewResult Index() {
     //call various methods on the mocked and nonmocked members
     return View();
   }
}
```

In other words, I'd like to create a mock home controller and mock some local variables within it and their methods-- but not all of them.  Is this possible using Rhino?

Comment: What Type of myObjectType? an interface or normal class?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject these through constructor parameters. Just write constructor that takes myObjectType as parameter. Within this constructor just initialize your fields.

**Note1:** in case to run MVC, you will need also parameterless ctro, or modify ConstructorFactory (e.g. here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/560798/ASP-NET-MVC-Controller-Dependency-Injection-for-Be). Or just think about using some IoC container (e.g. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/) that can inject whatever you want inside the controller (mock or normal class).

**Note2:** you should extract an interface from myObjectType class and mock that interface instead of concrete class (Rhino handles that better).

**Note3:** I am usually trying to put all the logic (and test that separately)  outside of controller since it is quite tough to test the controller (you need to initialize a lot of stuff there what involves another mocking).